# Apache Ignite: node in maintenance mode

Tags: ignite

I wonder what is the mitigation plan for a situation when a node started up in maintenance mode? My node start up in maintenance mode and it's not clear what to do next. I assume it's fixing up some data issues but it doesn't seem to restart or exit maintenance mode automatically when it's done.
I'm running Ignite v2.14 with persistence on.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted Node in maintenance mode mean that there's some corrupted on your caches, you can use control.sh to check persistence of cache. Maybe you have to clear corrupted cache before manualy restart your node

Comment: Thank you, what exactly command of control.sh should I use for that?

Comment: ./control.sh --persistence info -> check corrupted caches. ./control.sh -persistence clean corrupted -> clean corrupted caches